# how to change stream index in libavformat

Tags: libavformat

I'm a newbie in ffmpeg. I have a problem when some media has multiple audio streams.
Suppose in MKV file, it has three audio streams (MP3, WMA and WMAPro)

How do I change the stream index when demuxing using:

```
AVPacket inputPacket;
ret = av_read_frame(avInputFmtCtx, &inputPacket)
```

So I'm searching something like change_stream_index(int streamindex), and when I call that function (suppose change_stream_index(2)), the next call to av_read_frame will demux WMAPro frame instead of MP3.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem today and in my case I deal with a mp4 file with 80 tracks and obviously if you just need to demux a single track you don't want to skip up to 79 packets each time you want to process a single packet from a selected stream.

The solution for me was setting the `discard` attribute of all streams which I'm not interested in to `AVDISCARD_ALL`. For example in order to select only a single stream with index 71 you can do this:

```
int32_t stream_index = 71;
for(int32_t i = 0; i<pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
{
  if(stream_index != i) pFormatContext->streams[i]->discard = AVDISCARD_ALL;
}
```

after this you can call `av_seek_frame` or `av_read_frame` and only track 71 is processed.

Just for the reference, here is the list of all available discard types:

```
AVDISCARD_NONE    =-16, ///< discard nothing
AVDISCARD_DEFAULT =  0, ///< discard useless packets like 0 size packets in avi
AVDISCARD_NONREF  =  8, ///< discard all non reference
AVDISCARD_BIDIR   = 16, ///< discard all bidirectional frames
AVDISCARD_NONINTRA= 24, ///< discard all non intra frames
AVDISCARD_NONKEY  = 32, ///< discard all frames except keyframes
AVDISCARD_ALL     = 48, ///< discard all
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first you check for the number of streams within the input. Then you write them in some buffer(in my case I only have 2 streams, but you can easily expand that)

```
ptrFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    if(avformat_open_input(&ptrFormatContext, filename, NULL, NULL) != 0 )
    {
        qDebug("Error opening the input");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(av_find_stream_info( ptrFormatContext) < 0)
    {
        qDebug("Could not find any stream info");
        exit(-2);
    }
    dump_format(ptrFormatContext, 0, filename, (int) NULL);

    for(i=0; i<ptrFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        switch(ptrFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type)
        {
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        {
            if(videoStream < 0) videoStream = i;
            break;
        }
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
        {
            if(audioStream < 0) audioStream = i;
        }
        }
    }
    if(audioStream == -1)
    {
        qDebug("Could not find any audio stream");
        exit(-3);
    }
    if(videoStream == -1)
    {
        qDebug("Could not find any video stream");
        exit(-4);
    }
```

Since you don't know in which order the streams come in, you'll also have to check for the name of the codec: `ptrFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_name` and then save the index for the regarding target_format.
Then you can just access the stream through the given index:

```
while(av_read_frame(ptrFormatContext,&ptrPacket) >= 0)
    {
        if(ptrPacket.stream_index == videoStream)
        {
            //decode the video stream to raw format
            if(avcodec_decode_video2(ptrCodecCtxt, ptrFrame, &frameFinished, &ptrPacket) < 0)
            {
                qDebug("Error decoding the Videostream");
                exit(-13);
            }
            if(frameFinished)
            {
                printf("%s\n", (char*) ptrPacket.data);
//encode the video stream to target format
//                av_free_packet(&ptrPacket);
            }
        }
        else if (ptrPacket.stream_index == audioStream)
        {
            //decode the audio stream to raw format
//            if(avcodec_decode_audio3(aCodecCtx, , ,&ptrPacket) < 0)
//            {
//                qDebug("Error decoding the Audiostream");
//                exit(-14);
//            }
            //encode the audio stream to target format
        }
    }
```

I just copied some extracts from a program of mine but this will hopefully help you to understand how to select streams from the input. 
I did not post complete code, only excerpts, so you will have to do some initialization etc on your own, but if you have any questions I'll gladly help you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Dimitri Podborski is good! But there's a small issue with that approach. If you inspect the code of `av_read_frame` function, you'll find that there can be two cases:

1. `format_context->flags & AVFMT_FLAG_GENPTS == true` - then OK, the approach works
2. `format_context->flags & AVFMT_FLAG_GENPTS == false` - then the discard field of a stream will be ignored, and av_read_frame will read all the packets.

So, obviously, you should go with the AVDISCARD_ALL approach, but in case of absence of the GENPTS flag - fallback to a classic stream index inspection.